Pycaret plot_model() crashing after closing plot
Is this a bug, or am I doing it wrong?
There's an issue with PyCaret plot_model() function. It does open the specified plot, but when closing the plot by clicking on the "X" mark or Ctrl+W the script crashes with following output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/./inverter_ML_regression_2F_test.py", line 69, in <module>
    experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'error')     # Prediction Error Plot
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycaret/regression/oop.py", line 1946, in plot_model
    return super().plot_model(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/tabular_experiment.py", line 2045, in plot_model
    return self._plot_model(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/tabular_experiment.py", line 1913, in _plot_model
    ret = locals()[plot]()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/tabular_experiment.py", line 1227, in error
    return show_yellowbrick_plot(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycaret/internal/plots/yellowbrick.py", line 115, in show_yellowbrick_plot
    visualizer.show(clear_figure=True)
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yellowbrick/base.py", line 249, in show
    self.fig.clear()
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3148, in clear
    super().clear(keep_observers=keep_observers)
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 978, in clear
    self.delaxes(ax)  # Remove ax from self._axstack.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 945, in delaxes
    self._axobservers.process("_axes_change_event", self)
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 319, in process
    self.exception_handler(exc)
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 103, in _exception_printer
    raise exc
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 314, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3253, in <lambda>
    self._axobservers.connect("_axes_change_event", lambda arg: func(arg))
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2848, in notify_axes_change
    self.toolbar.update()
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3382, in update
    self.set_history_buttons()
  File "/home/boris/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 892, in set_history_buttons
    self._buttons['Back']['state'] = state_map[can_back]
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1732, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1721, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1711, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!navigationtoolbar2tk.!button2"

Only plot that doesn't crash when closed is the 'pipeline' plot. All other plot types are crashing on close.
PyCaret version:
(inverter_virtualenv) boris@E5440-DELL:~/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv$ pip list | grep pycaret
pycaret                   3.3.2
(inverter_virtualenv) boris@E5440-DELL:~/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv$ pip list | grep yellowbrick
yellowbrick               1.5
(inverter_virtualenv) boris@E5440-DELL:~/Documents/EDU/AI-ML_examples/inverter_virtualenv$ pip list | grep matplotlib
matplotlib                3.7.5
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7

This is my code sample:
from pycaret.regression import *

experiment1 = RegressionExperiment()
experiment1.setup(X_train, target="delay")
print(experiment1)

top3_best = experiment1.compare_models(exclude=['lightgbm'], n_select=3)
print(top3_best)

initial_et = experiment1.create_model('et')
initial_rf = experiment1.create_model('rf')
initial_gbr = experiment1.create_model('gbr')
print(initial_et)
print(initial_rf)
print(initial_gbr)

#tuned_et = experiment1.tune_model(initial_et)
#tuned_rf = experiment1.tune_model(initial_rf)
tuned_gbr = experiment1.tune_model(initial_gbr)
#print(tuned_et)
#print(tuned_rf)
print(tuned_gbr)

experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'pipeline')  # Schematic drawing of the preprocessing pipeline
#experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'residuals') # Residuals Plot
experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'error')     # Prediction Error Plot
#experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'cooks')     # Cooks Distance Plot
#experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'rfe')       # Recursive Feat. Selection
experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'learning')  # Learning Curve
#experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'vc')        # Validation Curve
#experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'manifold')  # Manifold Learning
experiment1.plot_model(tuned_gbr, plot = 'feature')   # Feature Importance

